# Google Spreadsheets - How To Have 2 Functions Output Into 1 Box?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets and I'm currently trying to get multiple functions to output into 1 square. In my example:

```
={IF((B2-D2)>=0,"+"), SUM(B2-D2)}
```

I get the output I want `+7`, but it's in 2 different grid boxes `| + | 7 |`. How can I get both functions to output into the same box?

*And this is just an example, so don't get hung-up on alternative workarounds*

[**Google Spreadsheets Example**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LvH_8ZwTP5aJ3ta-J53QrrE-CZ0azU6RPXtSZ264I6g/edit#gid=0)

Comment: No alternative workarounds, right. But from your question, it looks like you are trying to do thing overly complicated. You will end up with a _string_ in the result cell, which is often not what I'd want in the end. You know that example could be solved with formatting, right?

Comment: @Vidar - I actually didn't know that. And, just curios, why do you consider strings bad?

Comment: @CSSApprentice You cannot do calculations (like `=SUM`) on strings (without converting them back to numbers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you have to use this formula:

```
=IF(B2-D2 >= 0, "+" & SUM(B2-D2))
```

The curly brackets are used for **[embedded arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)**